# gmail add-on detect if mobile device being used

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-addons

I have an add-on working in my computers browser and mobile device for gmail.

I need to know when the add-on is being rendered in the mobile device.

The reason being I already have an extension that does all I need in the browser and the add-on really is only needed for the mobile device (as I can't run the extension in the gmail app).

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Seems like the only option is to hack the dom using my extension and change the content of the add-on with a message stating the add-on is only for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be checked using `clientPlatform` property in action event object. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/actions#action_event_objects)  for details.